# Sort contact by name in IOS (Phonegap) (name display in Chinese and english )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, cordova

i have display all contact in screen which i want to sort by name, these all contacts in english and Chinese so when i sorted contact, all Chinese contact display at the end of the list, so any one know how to sort Chinese contact.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy,you need convert Chinese to Chinese pinyin(English words) first,here is javascript file do this.

https://code.google.com/p/pinyin-engine/;

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will try to integrate but here no instruction .

Comment: The instruction is in Chinese,download the code,then import file 'pinyinEngine.full.js' into your project.using pinyinEngine.toPinyin method is enoungh. Here is the example:var pinyin =pinyinEngine.toPinyin('Chinese word');